# getter return new instance or a copy

Tags: java

I have a rgb color class and a bulb light class.

**My question is**: what is the correct way to return `getColor` in bulb light class:

first option:

```
public RGBColor getColor()
{
    return _color;
}
```

second option:

```
public RGBColor getColor()
{
    return new RGBColor(_color);
}
```

BulbLight class:

```
private RGBColor _color;
public LightBulb (int red, int green, int blue )
{
    _color = new RGBColor(red,green,blue);

}
```

RGBColor class:

```
public class RGBColor {
    private int _red;
    private int _green;
    private int _blue;

    public RGBColor()
    {
        _red = 0;
        _green = 0;
        _blue = 0;
    }

    public RGBColor(RGBColor other)
    {
        _red = other._red;
        _green = other._green;
        _blue = other._blue;
    }
//... getter and setters for red, green, blue
}
```

Updated question:
my friend said that the first option is aliasing, I don't agree with him. is he right?

Comment: What is RGBColor class? Can you provide implementation?

Comment: We don't know what `RGBColor` is, so we can't really answer.  If you say `return _color`, you will return a reference to the same object that your private variable refers to.  If your class changes that `RGBColor` later (if it's not immutable), the return value will also point to the changed object.  But if you return `new RGBColor(_color)`, the return value will be a reference to a different object, so if you change one, the other won't be changed.  Which is right?  Not enough info to tell.

Comment: added implementation for RGBColor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think first option is the better way. You are creating a new color object for each LightBulb object, so instead of creating unnecessary color objects again in getColor method which can lead to memory issues, it is better to return the instance created for color in the constructor.

Since we dont know whether the RGBColor class is immutable or not.

Comment: my RGBColor can be updated so it's not immutable i can update it by the setters

Comment: my friend said that the first option is aliasing, i don't agree with him. is he right?

Comment: As it is clear from your code that the class is mutable, i would go by my answer that instead of creating new objects every time in getColor which might be called several times, thereby causing memory issues, it is better to use option one.

Comment: option one is aliasing?

Comment: No aliasing comes into picture when there is parent-child relationship.

Answer (score 4):

It really depends on what you want. Both options are legit for different cases.

Do you want the client who calls the getter to be able to change the object via reference, in a way that the object held inside `LightBulb` is changed? Use option one.

Do you not want the caller to be able to do that? Use option two.

Do you want the `RGBColor` object to never be able to change, even from inside `LightBulb`? Make `RGBColor` immutable.

Answer (score 3):

If the class `RGBColor` is immutable (i.e. an instance of `RGBColor` can not be changed after creation) I suggest that you simply return it.

However, if it is possible to change the values of an object of type `RGBColor` it is possible that by returning the object directly you expose to much information to the caller and the behaviour of the `LightBulb` can not be determined. In that case I would (possibly) return a copy.

But, IMO the best approach here is to make the `RGBColor` class immutable.

Example:

```
public class RGBColor {
    private final int blue;
    private final int green;
    private final int red;

    public RGBColor(final int red, final int green, final int blue) {
        this.red = red;
        this.green = green;
        this.blue = blue;
    }

    public int getBlue() {
        return blue;
    }

    public int getGreen() {
        return green;
    }

    public int getRed() {
        return red;
    }
}
```

**Edit:** After more input from the OP.
Since your `RGBColor` implementation contains "setters" I suggest that you return a copy. But, a better approach according to me is to make the class immutable as in the provided example.

Comment: is option one aliasing?